# Simulator Crashes with TextView and ImageView

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I recently started programing and when I did a basic *ImageView* and *TextView* shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView>
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/texttry" />
    </TextView>


    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/joe"
        android:src="@drawable/joe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The simulator crashed and the logcat gave this error:

```
11-24 11:09:20.938: D/AndroidRuntime(713): Shutting down VM
11-24 11:09:20.938: W/dalvikvm(713): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
11-24 11:09:20.938: E/AndroidRuntime(713): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tristan.wuker.wrje/tristan.wuker.wrje.MrttestActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #10: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #10: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:438)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3433)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3513)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1265)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1191)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:45)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1620)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at tristan.wuker.wrje.MrttestActivity.onCreate(MrttestActivity.java:11)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
11-24 11:09:20.958: E/AndroidRuntime(713):  ... 11 more
11-24 11:09:20.978: I/dalvikvm(713): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
11-24 11:09:20.978: E/dalvikvm(713): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

I am also new to this website so I am sorry if I posted this wrong.

**Also if it helps to know, when I take out ImageView the text works like a charm.**

Comment: please post your activity code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am sure you figured out in the end, the logs tell you where the problem is. Specifically this line (that I shortened so it fits):

```
11-24 11:09:20.958 .. Caused by.. #10: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

As you can see in the snippet below:

```
<TextView>
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/texttry" />
</TextView>
```

You closed the **<TextView\>** element too early, before specifying any attributes. The one that log mentions is _layout_width_.

All you have to do to fix this 'issue' is remove the right  shevron from the *TextView* element opening, like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/texttry" />
</TextView>
```

### Boom, done :)

*PS: One teeny tiny detail though `fill_parent` is depreciated, you should use `match_parent` instead:*

```
<TextView>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/texttry" />
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code just now and seems to work when I take out the closing `</TextView>` tag:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/texttry" />



    <ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/joe"
   android:src="@drawable/joe"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.  I believe that it is a problem with my Eclipse setup.  Any help is sell appreciated.

Comment: Is your source picture for the imageview in the correct place? You should make a new folder called 'drawable' in your 'res' folder and store your picture in there.

Comment: It is in my drawable folder. Whenever I run in the simulator I get an error the process android.proccess.acore has stopped unexpectedly. please try again.

Comment: Any Help is sell appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show me your project setup. I'm quite confused as it works like a charm when I change the TextView tags as shown above. I have edited my previous answer with the full XML code, see if it matches yours as well.

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean by project setup.

Comment: @TristanWiley How you've laid out your folders and stuff